# How to retrieve List View buttons using SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, vs-code

I am trying to retrieve the list view buttons settings from my Lead object but am unsure of how to capture this using VSCode Org or SFDX.

It is under Custom Objects > Leads > List View Button Layout.

There are no options pertaining to it in Org Browser, nothing under List View or Search Layout.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the list view buttons in the Object metadata file.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_searchlayouts.htm

You should be able to do

SFDX

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -p "path/to/objects/Lead/Lead.object-meta.xml"`

SF

`sf project retrieve start --source-dir "path/to/objects/Lead/Lead.object-meta.xml"`